# Does scaling etcd affect write performance?

Tags: performance, etcd, raft, horizontal-scaling

The distributed value-store [etcd](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd) uses the raft algorithm. The docs link to [animations](http://thesecretlivesofdata.com/raft/) explaining: how the replica nodes vote to make one node the leader (to be the recipient of external **write** instructions), and thereafter the leader broadcasts all instructions to all nodes (attaching those instructions to a heartbeat signal that is bounced off of the other nodes, in a star topology, with confirmation after a majority acknowledge).

The replication obviously provides resilience (against failures of individual nodes), and presumably the **read** performance scales up with replica count.

Is it correct to understand that **write** performance is constant, and does *not* scale with replica count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. **write** requires majority of nodes to ack new entry in order to commit it. It may happen that **write** is even slower with increased number of replicas (it is as fast as slowest node out of quorum). In regards to **read**, you might find [etcd docs about linearizability](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/learning/api_guarantees/#isolation-level-and-consistency-of-replicas) interesting. TL;DR; default **reads** also need quorum.